# How to get Divisions and regions of customers in a saved search?

Tags: netsuite

Can I create a saved search in NetSuite to display divisions and regions of customers?

I am trying to get division and regions off a saved search i.e. division and location of customer's transactions in a saved search.

Comment: You mean all the division and location of customer 's transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a search with following criteria

```
1) Customer : internalid anyof CUSTOMER_INTERNAL_ID
2) Mainline is T
3) Type anyof Sales Order, Cash Sale, ANY_OTHER_APPLICABLE_CUSTOMER_TRANASACTION
```

In the search column add

```
1) Department with summary type Group
2) Location with summary type Group
```

Remove any other search columns from the result as adding unwanted fields with incorrect grouping will lead to duplicate results

If you want to get departments and columns of all customers within a single search you can remove filter #1 and add a search column `customer with summary type as group`